# Find mails, pipe them to php and delete after

Tags: email, pipe, php, xargs

I have a script that saves to DB content of piped to it file.

```
cat /mailpath/Maildir/cur/mailfile | php -q /scriptpath/mailPipe.php
```

I need a shell script or oneliner to find all files in Maildir, pipe them to php script and delete every file after that.

I know how to find and pipe every single file to PHP

```
find /mailpath/Maildir/cur/ -type f -printf "cat %p | php -q /scriptpath/mailPipe.php\n" | sh
```

But don't know how to delete files after—I don't won't to experiment with `rm`

P.S. If someone needs similar script: https://github.com/stuporglue/mailreader

Comment: Frankly, if you aren't comfortable "experimenting" with `rm`, you shouldn't be doing this--unless the data you're messing with can be lost without consequences.  `rm` is just a command that deletes files; whether you do it with `find -delete` or `rm` or something else, the end result is the same.  Make--and test!--your backups first.

Comment: the data I'm messing with can be lost without consequences ;-) but thanks for the care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command should fails because the -delete is executed before the exec and also because in anycase your script only read input from stdin.

`find /mailpath/Maildir/cur/ -type f -delete -exec php -q /scriptpath/mailPipe.php  {} \;`

I suggest you this one now : 
`find . -type f -exec sh -c "php -q /scriptpath/mailPipe.php < '{}'" \; -delete`

Which produce this :

```
for i in `seq -w 1 10`; do echo $i > nonce-$i; done; ls 
nonce-01  nonce-02  nonce-03  nonce-04  nonce-05  nonce-06  nonce-07  nonce-08  nonce-09  nonce-10
```

Executing the find :

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "wc -l < '{}'" \; -delete ; ls
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Can you try that ? (make a backup of /mailpath/Maildir/cur/ before)

It's an all in one command, without piping find with other commands, which can be pretty confusing.

It's even better because if the return of sh is error, then it won't delete the file at all, the order of command in find are dependent.

Also i really advise your to read this http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind  you will find usefull information there

Comment: I've tried -delete with -printf but it deleted files before cat. Your code was strangely long executed and nothing happened. I will give it a try once more but I don't understand how can it work when you pipe a filename, not a file content to the script - I think "cat" is missing.

Comment: `find . -type f -exec sh -c "cat '{}' |wc -l" \; -delete` worked fine to me
try the other way around `find . -type f -exec sh -c "cat '{}' | php -q /scriptpath/mailPipe.php" \; -delete`

Comment: and again backup your server before testing it please ! :)

Comment: And please don't wait 6 hours to give me a feedback !

Comment: Sorry for the wait - there was night here ;-)

yesterday I wrote a simple script that does `find -delete` after `find cat | php`  but your solution `find . -type f -exec sh -c "cat '{}' | php -q /scriptpath/mailPipe.php" \; -delete` is clean and perfect.

Comment: in fact i dont like `cat file | command` that's why i suggested also to test `-exec sh -c "php -q /scriptpath/mailPipe.php < '{}'" \;` is it working ?